# jQuery: loading ID tag from database

Tags: jquery, database, radio-button, checked

So I have lots of radio buttons with same name but different ID and I wan't specific one of them to be selected on page load. The ID of desired button is saved to the database. I've tried this kind of solution for the actual ajax call, but alas it didn't work.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_config.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data)
        {
            var buttonID = "#"+data.buttonID; // data.buttonID = "button5"
            $(buttonID).attr("checked", true);
        }
});
```

while the HTML part is in this sorta manner, except with a whole lot more of buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="button1" name="example" value="value1"/>
<input type="radio" id="button2" name="example" value="value2"/>
<input type="radio" id="button3" name="example" value="value3"/>
<input type="radio" id="button4" name="example" value="value4"/>
<input type="radio" id="button5" name="example" value="value5"/>
```

Comment: What error message if any do you get?

Comment: Try this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CfWsc/. It works for me in FF3.6. Is your AJAX call succeeding? Is your data correct?

Comment: This seems correct, double check if `data.buttonID` is `button5` or if you have another `ID` called `button5` in your html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check your JSON coming back, your overall approach is correct, you can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/KuK3Z/

I would bet that your `data.buttonID` isn't *quite* what you think it is, or your code isn't running inside a `document.ready`, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_config.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data)
        {
            var buttonID = "#"+data.buttonID; // data.buttonID = "button5"
            $(buttonID).attr("checked", true);
        }
  });
});
```

If it's not running in a `document.ready` and your AJAX call finishes before your elements are ready, the `$("#button5")` selector won't find anything to check.  Alternatively, and much better if you can could be to just render a `checked="checked"` inside the correct `<input />` when you render the page, and eliminate the AJAX call altogether.

Comment: oh crapness. you're right, the data.buttonID came back as undefined. I was sure I checked it earlier, but have modified and typo'd it afterwards. kinda embarassing! but thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your data response:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_config.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data['buttonID']);
        }
  });
});
```

if is undefined check your php or my last solution, otherwise try:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_config.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#"+data['buttonID']).attr("checked",true);
        }
  });
});
```

I've a problem once time returning the Json to jquery, the json string was returned with many slashes...
try this in case the first solution gaves to you an error (this will report the string returned form server without decoding the json):

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_config.php",
        dataType: "text",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        }
  });
});
```

Sorry for my english. tell me something if it worked...

Comment: it was a typo I missed altogether, but thanks for the suggestion anyway.